# combine columns data into one row

Tags: php, mysql

I have query that returns the following result
Query :

```
SELECT 
    c.meetings_id, c.speakers_id, c.date_sent, c.check_type_id
from
    cf_checkings c
where
    c.void = '0'
```

Result :

```
 Meeting_id | Speaker_id | Date_sent | check_type_id
    33  4   2014-02-27  1
    34  200 2014-01-27  1
    34  200 2014-02-20  2
    35  30  2014-01-30  1
    35  30  2014-02-20  2
    35  31  2014-01-30  1
    35  31  2014-02-20  2 
   * 35 31  2014-02-22  2 *
```

I want the following result

```
Meeting_id | Speaker_id | Date_sent_1 | Date_sent_2
33              4         2014-02-27     
34             200        2014-01-27    2014-02-20
35             30         2014-01-30    2014-02-20 
35             31         2014-01-30    2014-02-22
```

Any one can help? 
*/ When result have two rows with same meeting_id,speaker_id and check_type_id then select max date_sent

I have to perform operation in query itself that is limitation I have. */

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: I have to do it in query.

Comment: Is it possible that there could be a `Date_sent_3`?

Comment: No. if it has two rows with same meeting_id,speaker_id and check_type_id then select max date_sent.

Comment: @kayra If that's the case, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. You may need to provide a more extensive data set in order to be properly representative.

Comment: Fiddle data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd55f4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by using `MIN,MAX`, and a `CASE` for `Date_sent_2` to check if it equals to the minimum of `date_sent` then show null

```
SELECT 
    c.meeting_id, 
    c.speaker_id,
    MIN(c.date_sent) Date_sent_1 , 
    (CASE WHEN MIN(c.date_sent) =MAX(c.date_sent)
    THEN NULL 
    ELSE MAX(c.date_sent)
    END) Date_sent_2 
  FROM 
        mf_checking  c
    WHERE c.void = '0' /* your where criteria */
    GROUP BY c.meeting_id, c.speaker_id
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a035/2)

**Edit from comments** you can also use case with in max function to pick the date that belongs to `check_type_id` 1 or 2

```
SELECT 
    c.meeting_id,
    c.speaker_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.check_type_id =1 
    THEN c.Date_sent END) Date_sent_1
    ,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.check_type_id =2 
    THEN c.Date_sent END) Date_sent_2
FROM
        mf_checking   c
    WHERE c.void = '0' /* your where criteria */
    GROUP BY c.meeting_id, c.speaker_id
```

### [Fiddle Demo 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a035/4)

Comment: @dowvoters please show some respect and leave a comment so the answer can be improved however you can visit the fiddle link before downvoting the answer

Comment: Meeting_id | Speaker_id | Date_sent | check_type_id
    33  4   2014-02-27  1
    34  200 2014-01-27  1
    34  200 2014-02-20  2
    35  30  2014-01-30  1
    35  30  2014-02-20  2
    35  31  2014-01-30  1
    35  31  2014-02-20  2

Comment: I have edit the question. Please see * * record and explanation.

Comment: I want results split by check_type_id 1 or 2 and combined into one row by two columns.  Where date_sent of check_type_id 1 goes to column date_sent_1 and  date_sent of check_type_id 2 goes to column date_sent_2. When it has two records which has two rows with same meeting_id,speaker_id and check_type_id then select max date_sent

Comment: its not yielding correct result for one record. Is there any way I can give you sample data again?